# Redirect /pagename to /#pagename

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I would like to get the following apache-redirect working:

When someone surfs to `mydomain.tld/contact`, they should be redirected to `mydomain.tld/#contact`.

This is because I built a one-page-website with autoscrolling.

This is not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php#$1 - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your example is missing things you are asking for. E.g. `RewriteRule ^index.php\/(.*)$ \#$1`

Comment: Thanks for your comments @pduersteler, but after changing my RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^index.php\/(.*)$ \#$1` it still won't work.

Comment: I see you updated your code, but you updated wrong. I think you need to read the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule. You are missing some things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite following what your existing rules are going for, but I believe you want something like this:

```
RewriteBase /
# Send a request for / (or /#something) to /index.php:
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
# Redirect a request for /something to /#something, assuming it's not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ #$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```